# Integration test for the flow (Java DSL configuration)

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I am trying to implement some tests for the flow configuration. I have JMS inbound channel adapter as an entry point of the flow and outbound file channel adapter(with attached ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice) as a last endpoint.

Here is a sample code:

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow fileProcessingFlow() {
    DefaultMessageListenerContainer dmlc = new DefaultMessageListenerContainer();
    dmlc.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
    dmlc.setDestination(jmsQueue);

    return IntegrationFlows.from(Jms.messageDrivenChannelAdapter(dmlc))
        .<String, File>transform(p -> new File(p))
        .handle(headerEnricherService)
        .<Boolean>route("T(SomeEnum).INVALID.equals(headers['headerName'])", mapping -> mapping 
            .subFlowMapping(Boolean.TRUE, sf -> sf.handle(serviceRef, "handleInvalidFile"))
            .subFlowMapping(Boolean.FALSE, sf -> sf
                .handle(serviceRef, "handleValidFile")
                .handle(anotherServiceRef)))
        .filter(additionalFilterRef)
        .handle(Files.outboundAdapter("'output/dir/path'")
                     .autoCreateDirectory(true)
                     .deleteSourceFiles(true),
                c -> c.advice(fileCopyAdvice()))
        .get();
}
```

I was using this article to implement code above - https://spring.io/blog/2014/11/25/spring-integration-java-dsl-line-by-line-tutorial . However, I was not able to find information about testing of that code.

I've got several questions regarding code above:

1. Where can I find test example(s) for the similarly defined flow? Or at least, some tutorial or articles on the subject?
2. What would be the best way to mock JMS connection?
3. How can I get references to the channels, when they are not explicitly defined in the flow config? Preferably, I would like to autowire channel in my test config and then to send a sample message to it. Something like `jmsInputChannel.send(testMessage);`
4. Is there any way to use MessageHistory in the test?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, Alex,

Since you can't find any samples, nor articles or anything else, that means that there is just no like that.

Just because Spring Integration doesn't have an opinionated testing tool.

We still try to come up with something and encourage community to share their thoughts on the matter: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-java-dsl/issues/23.

As you see not so much progress.

Now let me try to answer to your other questions.

We uses real embedded ActiveMQ for testing. It just starts broker automatically via `ConnectionFactory` and properly populate all the destinations. Although you can find some `Stub*` classes in the `spring-integration-jms` tests: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/tree/master/spring-integration-jms/src/test/java/org/springframework/integration/jms

You can get references to those implicit channels as well: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-java-dsl/wiki/Spring-Integration-Java-DSL-Reference#message-channels :

> By default endpoints are wired via `DirectChannel` where the bean name is based on the pattern: `[IntegrationFlow.beanName].channel#[channelNameIndex]`.

So, in your case the channel after `Jms.messageDrivenChannelAdapter()` and before `transform()` has a bean name like `fileProcessingFlow.channel#0`.

Not sure in your concern about `MessageHistory`. You can simply add one more `@Configuration` class to your test harness where you can declare `@EnableMessageHistory`.

Comment: Hi Artem. Thanks a lot for the detailed response.